# How to solve URL in bibliography overflowing the margin of the document in Latex?

Tags: url, latex, bibtex, bibliography

I tried to include a website URL into the Latex bibliography. URL reference is too big and so that it overflows the document.

Following is the bibliography entry.

```
@misc{httpsloc53:online,
author = {},
title = {https://localwiki.org/oakland/A\%27s\_20\_Game\_Streak - Google Search},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.google.com/search?ei=BAuZX5yHA8DXz7sP_pq9wA4&q=https%3A%2F%2Flocalwiki.org%2Foakland%2FA%2527s_20_Game_Streak&oq=https%3A%2F%2Flocalwiki.org%2Foakland%2FA%2527s_20_Game_Streak&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1CVnwpYlZ8KYPqjCmgAcAB4AIABwgGIAcIBkgEDMC4xmAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwicmdqC0NbsAhXA63MBHX5ND-gQ4dUDCA0&uact=5}},
month = {},
year = {},
note = {(Accessed on 08/04/2020)}
}
```

This is how it appears in the document.
[image]

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Try the `xurl` package. If this does not help, please make a [mre]

Comment: had this same problem and xurl worked for me! great tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer was given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256190) by using the package `\usepackage{breakurl}` and define a possible breakline for the `/` or `-` symbols thanks to `\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}`

The second point is that your url is quite long (you have 3 times `https:://`) and can be shortened

Comment: I tried this and even the one you shared via the link. None of them worked.  I am using the overleaf platform and this happened the first time.